# Display a subset of a data frame in a Shiny app

Tags: shiny

New to Shiny, I am trying to create a very simple app respecting the following sequence of events:

(1) Upload a dataframe,

(2) Wait until the user set the filtering parameter (`Category` in the example below),

(3) Press a `Go!` button,

(4) Display the first rows of the subset data frame.

Let's say I have a file `df.tab` to upload and process.

```
df <- data.frame(Category=c("A","A","A","B","B","B"), X=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), Y=c(1,2,3,34,21,1))
df
  Category X  Y
1        A 1  1
2        A 2  2
3        A 3  3
4        B 1 34
5        B 2 21
6        B 3  1
write.table(df, file="df.tab", row.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t")
```

My `app.R` looks like:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("input_df",label=h4("Dataset")),

            selectInput("category",h4("Category"), choices = list("A" = 1,"B" = 2),selected = 1),

            actionButton("goButton",label = "Go!")  
        ),

        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("view")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

    data <- eventReactive(
        input$input_df,
        {
            File <- input$input_df

            if(is.null(File)){
                return(NULL)
            }else{
                df <- read.table(File$datapath, header = T, sep = "\t")
            }
        }
    )

    data_sub <- eventReactive(
        input$category,
        {   
            df_sub <- subset(data(), Category == input$category)
        }
    )

    output$view <- renderTable(
        {
            head(data_sub())
        }
    )
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, the app is either not responsive or does not display any rows.

Note that I created 2 distinct reactive events `data` and `data_sub` in order to avoid loading the file every time I select a different category (and potentially to avoid stack errors with a recursive function).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working `server` function. Use `reactive`, not `eventReactive` and it is quite straightforward.

NOTE that your example assumes you have a Category column, I modified below to make it work with anything.

```
# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  dataset <- reactive({

      File <- input$input_df
      req(File)

      read.table(File$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
  })

  data_sub <- reactive({
    if("Category" %in% names(dataset())){
      subset(dataset(), Category == input$category)
    } else {
      dataset()
    }
  })

  output$view <- renderTable({
      head(data_sub())
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, still the same problem: nothing is displayed.

Comment: It works fine - I just forgot an extra `(` - please try the edited server function

Comment: I saw the missing `(`. Sorry but still does not work. Just the header is displayed. I am running `shiny_1.4.0`.

Comment: It really does work here. Have you tried selecting some file that does not have a Category column? Then the head() of all data should be displayed